# How to make group by inside group by in LINQ to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ to Entiy :

```
        var grouppedClientFullReview = (from cfr in clientFullReview
                                        group cfr by new { cfr.clientId, cfr.clientName } into g
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            siteNumbers = g.Select(x => x.siteId).Count(),
                                            clientId = g.Key.clientId,
                                            clientName = g.Key.clientName,
                                            WorkPlanReview = new
                                            {
                                                frequency = g.Select(x => x.inspectionFrequency),
                                                isNormal = g.Any(x => x.isNormal == false) ? false : true,
                                                objectsID = g.Select(x => x.objectID).ToArray(),
                                            }
                                        }).ToList();
```

I need to implement group by in WorkPlanReview property.

My question is how can I implement group by inside WorkPlanReview?
Is it posible to make nested group by?

Comment: Like insert `.GroupBy(g => g.WorkPlanReview)` right before `.ToList()`? What do you mean by **inside**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by the `WorkPlanReview` property itself, then you can end your query in the following way:

```
}).GroupBy(g => g.WorkPlanReview).ToList();
```

If you want to group on one of `WorkPlanReview`'s properties, here's how to achieve it:

```
}).GroupBy(g => g.WorkPlanReview.frequency).ToList();
```